# "account on" vs. "account of"

Tags: prepositions

Is there a semantic difference in the following two sentences?

1. > A brief *account on* the different techniques is given below.
2. > A brief *account of* the different techniques is given below.

Or is it just a matter of preference?

Source examples:

1. > A phenomenological *account of* the different perspectives of physician and patient.

   <sup>([Google Books: The Meaning of Illness](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=f2XCHFL-hDIC&pg=PA86&dq=%22brief+account+on+the+different%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22brief%20account%20on%20the%20different%22&f=false))</sup>
2. > For a brief *account on* the different approaches to collective intentionality see, F Hindriks […]. Hindriks advocates the importance of collective intentionality for any adequate analysis of social institutions.

   <sup>([Google Books: The Idea of Authorship in Copyright](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=llZtCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22account+of+the+different%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22account%20of%20the%20different%22&f=false))</sup>

Comment: You should add the immediate quotations (the paragraph including 1. and the title including 2.) from your sources to your question. The difference lies in what "account" is referring to.

Comment: @user3169: I've expanded the example quotes.

Comment: Both your links point to the same source. [Here's](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=f2XCHFL-hDIC&pg=PA86&dq=%22the+idea+of+authorship+in+copyright%22+%22brief+account+on+the+different+approaches%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIn6fB6IvRAhXBTrwKHTzYDZ8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20idea%20of%20authorship%20in%20copyright%22%20%22brief%20account%20on%20the%20different%20approaches%22&f=false) a link that might be more useful for the second reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Briefly, the "on" version deals with selected aspects of the subject, while the "of" version deals with the details of the subject as a whole.

First, let's look at the more common phrase, "an account of":

> **account** *noun*
>   1 A report or description of an event or experience: ‘a detailed account of what has been achieved’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/account)

It may be detailed, brief, or (arguably) even filtered, but the *event* itself, to the full extent of its breadth, forms the content delivered by the report or description.

Now, on to the other phrase, "an account on".

Scholarly titles often use the formulation "On [subject]" to indicate that the authors are writing about the said subject, but not doing so exhaustively. Here's one I picked at random:

> [On the Theory of Quantum Mechanics](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/112/762/661), P. A. M. Dirac, Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A 1926 112 661-677; DOI: 10.1098/rspa.1926.0133. Published 1 October 1926

The pages 661 to 677 span only 17 pages, not nearly enough to cover every aspect of quantum mechanics. Dirac indicates in the paper that he is focusing on Shrodinger's "new development of the theory". It is an exploration of a selected topic *within the field of* the theory of quantum mechanics.

This notion of focusing on selected items of interest in a subject carries through to giving accounts "on" the subject.

The phrase "account on the" is markedly less prevalent in Ngram's database than "on account of the", as @FumbleFingers points out (though he uses a slightly different search key). Have a look at the following [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=account%20on%20the%2Caccount%20of%20the&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Caccount%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Baccount%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAccount%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Caccount%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Baccount%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAccount%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

There are nevertheless several examples. Here's one:

> [An Account on the Life and Writings of David Hume](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=xzb8dlXj-zUC&pg=PA41&dq=%22account%20on%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie5eWZ4IvRAhVLbbwKHY9WAnEQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22account%20on%20the%22&f=false), by Thomas Edward Ritchie.

The [preface](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=xzb8dlXj-zUC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22an%20account%20on%20the%20life%20and%20writings%20of%20david%20hume%22&source=bl&ots=HMfjAMywNy&sig=8rAbQFH7O18c6O_z831-s8n73gk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjquq3G4ovRAhWHTLwKHXgMB1AQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=%22an%20account%20on%20the%20life%20and%20writings%20of%20david%20hume%22&f=false) starts with the following paragraph (quoted verbatim, emphasis in the original):

> In the following work I have introduced Mr. Hume's espistolary correspondence into the narrative, instead of relegating it to the appendix. The *letters* of a man, eminent for his learning and talents, form an interesting part of his biography; yet, when a collection of them is given without any connecting detail, every one must feel, that their value is considerably diminished: few indeed have perseverance to peruse them. By the plan I have adopted, the volume still remains the same in point of size; but the reader becomes progressively acquainted with the literary connections of Mr. Hume, the habits of him and his friends, and numberless traits in their characters, which could not be easily of advantageously compressed into history.

As is evident, this is not an account *of* David Hume's life, but rather a focus on his correspondence and the context surrounding that correspondence.

I'll end this answer by looking briefly at your examples (NB: your question linked the second example to the source of the first; I have expanded the quote using [this source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=f2XCHFL-hDIC&pg=PA86&dq=%22the%20idea%20of%20authorship%20in%20copyright%22%20%22brief%20account%20on%20the%20different%20approaches%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIn6fB6IvRAhXBTrwKHTzYDZ8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20idea%20of%20authorship%20in%20copyright%22%20%22brief%20account%20on%20the%20different%20approaches%22&f=false) for your second example):

- A phenomenological account of the different perspectives of physician and patient.

This reads to me as a report that details the different perspectives, from a 'phenomenological' perspective.

- For a brief account on the different approaches to collective intentionality see, F Hindriks, 'Social Groups, Collective Intentionality and Anti-Hegelian Skepticism' in […]. Hindriks advocates the importance of collective intentionality for any adequate analysis of social institutions.

This reads to me as a report of selected aspects of the different approaches, focusing on the relationships among the three topics listed in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is very subtle.

1. *Account on* has a connotation of a one-sided lecture on a topic.
2. *Account of* has a connotation of giving a detailed overview about a topic.

Comment: Nah. The difference isn't subtle at all - it's just that [nobody ever uses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gave+an+account+on%2Cgave+an+account+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgave%20an%20account%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgave%20an%20account%20of%3B%2Cc0) the construction *an account **on** [subject of the account]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *"nobody ever uses"* is too much of a strong statement to make here. There are *[a few to do use **account on**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=account+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccount%20on%3B%2Cc0)*, only that the number is seems negligible in comparison.

Comment: It's pretty meaningless to just show that the two words **account on** do in fact occur consecutively many times in the vast Google Books corpus. It flatlines if you include **account of** in the same chart, besides which almost every *actual* occurrence of ***account on*** will be some kind of "accidental collocation", not part of a noun phrase such as ***an account of [some subject]***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: so to be direct, is it inadvisable to use *'account on'*? If so, could you please state it as an answer.

Comment: @Ébe Isaac: Well, you can draw your own conclusions from my "nobody ever uses" link above. There are actually only a few dozen instances of ***gave an account on*** in Google Books, so you could look at all of them in context if you wanted. Many are irrelevant to the specific usage you're asking about *(the conspiracy of which he gave an **account on** the 4th of June, Cyrus gave an **account on** a clay cylinder of his conquest of Babylon, etc.)*. There are a (very) few relevant usages, and it's not inherently ungrammatical, but I'd certainly say it's "inadvisable" for you to use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Nice to know. Why not state it as an answer? (I'd upvote it) I see too many of your comments to be probably good answers.

Comment: @Ébe Isaac: I might post an answer eventually, if no-one else does. But I don't really have anything to add to what I've already said in comments, so there's no real gain for *you*. I'm still wondering why no-one has upvoted the question (yet three people have *closevoted* for lack of "detail"). All we've got so far is one upvote for Susannah's answer here, cancelled out by my downvote.